# How to write a for_each loop with IDE-managed Components in c++builder

Tags: c++, foreach, c++builder

I am new to c++ (c++builder) and was wondering, how i could write for each loops, which loop for example through all the TTabItem's in my TTabControll.

```
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
TTabControl *TabControl1;
TTabItem *TTabItem1;
TTabItem *TTabItem2;
```

Now i want to do something like:

```
for (auto &tTableItem : TabControl1) 
{  
    \\ Do something with the curent TEdit
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the C++ standard:

> 6.5.4 The range-based for statement [stmt.ranges]
>
> 1. A range-based for statement is equivalent to

```
{
  auto && __range = for-range-initializer;
  for ( auto __begin = begin-expr,
             __end = end-expr;
        __begin != __end;
        ++__begin ) {
    for-range-declaration = *__begin;
    statement
  }
}
```

This means that you have to provide a [`begin-expr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and an [`end-expr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) for your range.

An example for how to do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Container {
 public:
    using iterator = typename std::vector<int>::iterator;

    Container(std::initializer_list<int> list) : v_(list) {}

    iterator begin() { return v_.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return v_.end(); }

 private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
};

int main() {
    Container c{1, 2, 3, 42};

    for (auto& elem : c) {
        std::cout << elem << '\n';
    }
}
```

Since I'm guessing you can't modify the source code of the TTabControl class in order to provide said begin and end expressions you can derive your own TTabControl:

```
class MyTabControl : public TTabControl {
 public:
    // begin and end member functions
}
```

Or if you don't absolutely want to use ranged-for the [`TTabControl::GetChildren()`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TWinControl_GetChildren.html) method sounds promising.